# VueJS: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I start my simple project with VueJS and Vuex. And I have a problem witch calling method from store.
When I click my button in console I see this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined at VueComponent.onSignin
```

Here is my component with button which should call `dispatch`
[Login component](https://bitbucket.org/kudlaty9102/flashcards/raw/334e30dc12e9f0417f2d07827c6fde2426e1eb83/src/components/Login.vue).

And here is my store index.js
[Vuex.Store](https://bitbucket.org/kudlaty9102/flashcards/raw/334e30dc12e9f0417f2d07827c6fde2426e1eb83/src/store/index.js)

[And here you can find full repo](https://bitbucket.org/kudlaty9102/flashcards/src/help/)

I read many topics on another forum but I stil don't know why it is not work, because I do similar project few months ago and it works correctly.

Comment: I have noticed that in the Login component you call this.$store.dispatch('signUserIn') but in your vuex store in the actions there is not such an action. The only action is onUserLogin . You should make an action called signUserIn

Comment: Good attention, but it still doesn't work. I pushed again with correct name of action.

Comment: Can you please make also an update in action signUserIn(payload) to signUserIn(context,payload) and remove methods attribute in vuex store

Comment: Hmm I do this, and it still doesn't work. If I good remember you should have permission  to update 'help' branch. Fell free to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your store should be:

`export default new Vuex.Store({`

and not

`export const store = new Vuex.Store({`

Comment: Yes, it is! Now it works. Thank you very much. I felt that is something small, but important. I have to small reputation to give +1 for your answer.

Comment: Great! can you mark the answer as correct for future reference? thanks