# export default new Vuex.Store and Mutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have problem with using `commit` like is described [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html). Probably problem is in that I use `export default new Vuex.Store` instead `export const store = new Vuex.Store`. But when I change this I have problem from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301772/vuejs-cannot-read-property-dispatch-of-undefined).

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/kudlaty9102/flashcards/src/help/src/store/index.js) is my JS file, where I use Vuex and I want to call `commit`:

```js
actions: {
  signUserIn(payload) {
    payload.password;
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("grant_type", "password");
    params.append("username", "admin");
    params.append("password", "adminPassword");
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:8090/oauth/token",
      auth: { username: "my-trusted-client", password: "secret" },
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
      },
      data: params
    }).then(function(response) {
      const user = {
        login: payload.username
      };
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.data.access_token);
      this.commit("setUser", user);
    });
  }
},
```

Curently when I run this and I try call `signUserIn` I have this error in console: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'commmit' of undefined`

I don't have idea what can I type in google in this case.

Comment: There's not enough context. Can you update the question to show (1) the definition of `store`, and (2) the usage of the exported `store`?

Comment: @tony19 I added a link to my repo, and more specifically to file where I have a problem. I hope that now it is more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have mistyped. It should be `commit` and not `commmit`.

EDIT: Seeing the file, please try using arrow functions instead.

```
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8090/oauth/token",
    auth: { username: "my-trusted-client", password: "secret" },
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    },
    data: params
  }).then(response => {
    const user = {
      login: payload.username
    };
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.data.access_token);
    this.commit("setUser", user);
  });
```

This is because you will lose the context of `this` without it. With arrow functions, `this` remains the `this` from the outer context. Also, not sure if you need `this` in this particular case, but try with or without it. ( I said this too many times )

Comment: Nope:( Still the same situation. I pushed corrected version.

Comment: I haven't seen the JS file the first time, a mistake on my part. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note the signature of your action method is incorrect. The [Vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) show that the action method takes the Vuex context (which contains the `commit` method) as the first parameter and the payload second:

```
// signUserIn(payload) { // DON'T DO THIS
signUserIn(context, payload) {
```

With your current code, you'll notice that `payload.username` and `payload.password` are undefined.

[demo of your action with the bug](https://codesandbox.io/s/lr43m9y2nl)

Your action method should look like this:

```
actions: {
  signUserIn(context, payload) {
    axios.post().then(response => {
      context.commit('foo', foo);
    });
  }
}
```

[demo of fix](https://codesandbox.io/s/5w5pyo07op)